# Powerpoint Conversion to JPEG with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, jpeg, powerpoint

I have a client in need of an application that uploads a powerpoint file to a web app that can display the slides as jpegs (or flash, silverlight, HTML, video.. any format really) using ASP.NET.

I built the application with MVC in VS 2010 using Office developer tools but the clients server does not have Powerpoint and it seems the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint assembly won't function if it can't call Powerpoint on the host machine.

I've looked at every possible discussion dealing with this, the majority conclude its bad practice to even have Powerpoint deployed on a server, so my question is does anyone know of a utility that can convert PPT slide to JPG or Flash or anything to present the slides on a website?

Comment: Interop is more or less the .NET equivalent of a type library in COM.  It's like the card catalog of a library.  It tells the client application what's there and where to find it.  It's not the books itself.  MS recommends against automating Office apps on the server but with care, it can be done.  PPT doesn't allow multiple instances of itself, so you have to present it one task at a time and not try to launch another task/instance until you're sure the first has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with the use of Interop object..

```
    private void mConvertPPT_To_Images(string sPPTFilePath, string sImagesDirectoryPath)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application appPpt = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation objActivePresentation
                = appPpt.Presentations.Open(sPPTFilePath,
                                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue,
                                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed,
                                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
            //objActivePresentation.SaveAs(sImagesDirectoryPath, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
            //objActivePresentation.Export(sImagesDirectoryPath + @"\Slide1.png", "png", 960, 720);
            //objActivePresentation.SaveAs(sImagesDirectoryPath + "slide", PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsTIF, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide objSlide in objActivePresentation.Slides)
            {
                //Names are generated based on timestamp. 
                //objSlide.Export("Slide" + i, "PNG", 960, 720);
                objSlide.Export(sImagesDirectoryPath + @"\Slide" + i + ".GIF", "GIF", 960, 720);
                i++;
            }
            objActivePresentation.Close();
            appPpt.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s a solution by iSpring called iSpring Platform (http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring-platform). This is an SDK that allows software using .NET to convert PPT presentations to HTML5 and Flash. It supports all the effects, animations, and other PowerPoint stuff.

P.S. Looked at the post data and realized that the author had probably found the solution. Maybe my answer will be of use for someone else.